# GulpJS: How to rev images and then update their refs in css files?

Tags: build, gulp

```
gulp.task('usemin', function () {

  return gulp.src(path.src + '*.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
      assetsDir: 'src',
      css: [ minifyCss(), 'concat', rev()],
      js: [uglify(), rev()],
      images: [rev()]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist));
});
```

It does not work on the images.

Comment: Looking for solution, too. Seems that https://github.com/smysnk/gulp-rev-all is an approach.

Answer (score 1):

The philosophy of [gulp-rev-all](https://github.com/smysnk/gulp-rev-all) is to me a good way to see asset revisioning. It's very [well explained](https://github.com/smysnk/gulp-rev-all#why-fork) in their *Readme* that the hash should also take into account the reference(s) between revisioned files.

I've mocked up a little example that minify an image and a css file which use a `background url` property to see the revision of the new image path.

```
gulp.task('image', function () {
  return gulp.src('image.jpeg')
    .pipe(img({ progressive: false }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('tmp'));
});

gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src('test.css')
    .pipe(css())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('tmp'));
});

gulp.task('rev', ['image', 'css'], function () {
  return gulp.src('tmp/**')
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

I've removed all the fancy stuff to be more clear, but you can see the whole example [here](https://gist.github.com/Apercu/47f9d23c4b3f2c68bc08).